# melt() is using all column names as id variables

Tags: r, reshape2, melt

So, with ths dummy dataset

```
test_species <- c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e")
test_abundance <- c(4, 7, 15, 2, 9)
df <- rbind(test_species, test_abundance)
df <- as.data.frame(df)
colnames(df) <- c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e")
df <- dplyr::slice(df, 2)
```

we get a dataframe that's something like this:

```
a     b     c     d     e    
4     7     15    2     9
```

I'd like to transform it into something like

```
species      abundance
a            4
b            7
c            15
d            2
e            9
```

using the reshape2 function melt(). I tried the code

```
melted_df <- melt(df,
              variable.name = "species", 
              value.name = "abundance")
```

but that tells me: "Using a, b, c, d, e as id variables", and the end result looks like this:

```
a     b     c     d     e    
4     7     15    2     9
```

What am I doing wrong, and how can I fix it?

Comment: I don't know `reshape2`, but if you just want to get the result, use `tidyr::gather(df, "species", "abundance")`

Comment: with reshape2 you should be able to force this by giving the measure.vars parameter. melt(df, measure.vars = names(df))

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Rbind is adding some odd behaviour I think, I cannot explain why.

A fairly basic fix is:

```
test_species <-c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e")
test_abundance <- c(4, 7, 15, 2, 9)
df <- data.frame(test_species, test_abundance) #skip rbind and go straight to df
colnames(df) <- c('species', 'abundance') #colnames correct
```

This skips the rbind function and will give desired outcome.

Comment: The "odd" behaviour of `rbind()` is easily explained. `rbind()` creates a *matrix* from the given vectors, and as all elements of a matrix do have the same type, all matrix elements are coerced to character. For details, please, see `help("rbind")`.

Comment: Thanks, very helpful 

Answer (score 2):

You can define it in the correct shape from the start, using only base library functions:

```
> data.frame(species=test_species, abundance=test_abundance)
  species abundance
1       a         4
2       b         7
3       c        15
4       d         2
5       e         9
```

Comment: Or, if they need to go from there data frame, `data.frame(species = names(df), abundance = unlist(df[1, ]))`